# SSRS 2008r2 - how do I check to see who changed folder permissions

Tags: logging, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

So, on May 4 I added a newly created AD group to two SSRS folders to give users browse access.  I tested with several users and they were able to gain access to the subject folders because of their AD group membership.

I used this url and hovered over the folders and chose security and added browser rights for the mentioned AD group

http://my-sqlserver/Reports_Native_DHBI/Pages/Folder.aspx?ViewMode=Detail

FAST FORWARD TO TODAY:

Today, May 9, I appear in the office and the users are again complaining that they cannot see the subject report folders.  So, I go over to SSRS, check and discover that the rights I added on May 4, as noted above, were GONE for these folders.  I went in the same way to discover this (I re-added the AD group and the users were fine again btw):

http://mysqlserver/Reports_Native_DHBI/Pages/Folder.aspx?ViewMode=Detail

Question:  Can someone tell me where to look in the ReportServer db to discover how these rights were removed, because I know I did not do it.  :)

Thanks!

Comment: Was your ReportServer DB Restored? It could have rewritten the access.

Comment: No, the sys admin told me no server restore.  Still would like to know which table in the report server db can point me to when and how this happened!